# Dynamic Structure of Arrays, Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, structure

i am writing a prgram thats supposed to do the following

```
-open file
-read file
-tokenize file,getting name,course,grade tokens
-dynamiclly add these tokens to an array of structures
```

the file has the folowing format

```
Khai,IE 3301,69
Ashley,MATH 1426,59
Alisaad,CSE 1325,31
August,CSE 1325,55
Ethan,CSE 1320,92
```

but i keep on getting a segmentation fault that i do not understand, i looked at the indexes and they dont seem to go out of bounds so im not sure whats going on. The following is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct info {
char* student;
char* courseName;
int grade;
};



int main(void)
{
    char buffer[100];
    struct info **strarray = NULL;  /*struct of Arrays*/
    char* token;
    char* studen = (char *) malloc(15);
    char* coursename = (char *) malloc(10);
    int grad = malloc(sizeof(int)),count = 0,index = 0;
    char* del = ",";
    FILE* fp = fopen("input-hw05a.csv","r");

    while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp) != NULL)
    {
        token = strtok(buffer,del);
        studen = token;
        while(token != NULL)
        {
            if(count == 1)
                coursename = token;
            if(count ==2)
            grad = atoi(token);

            token = strtok(NULL,del);
            count = count + 1;
        }
        /*add ONE element to the array*/
        strarray = (struct info **)realloc(strarray,(index + 1) * sizeof(struct info *));

        /*allocate memory for struct info*/
        strarray[index] = (struct info *)malloc(sizeof(struct info));

        /*copy data inso structure array*/
        strcpy(strarray[index]->student,studen);
        strcpy(strarray[index]->courseName,coursename);
        strarray[index]->grade = grad;
        index = index + 1;
    }
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %s %d\n",strarray[i]->student,strarray[index]->courseName,strarray[index]->grade);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you think `strarray[index]->student` points to when you execute that `strcpy()`? The same goes for `strarray[index]->courseeName`. They're *both* indeterminate, and with that you invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: sorry but whats indeterminate,dont the point to the members of the structures?

Comment: `int grad = malloc(sizeof(int))` is wrong. Should be a compiler warning. Something like `warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]`

Comment: i got that warning but i was wondering how do i properly allocate space for an interger? i was going with sizeofint so it could apply to all types of computers

Comment: `int grad;` will give you space for 1 integer, no malloc needed

Comment: @ZachSantiago the pointers *are* the members of the struct. what they point *to* is the indeterminate state. You never allocate memory for your dynamic strings. Though not standard C, you can probably address that problem quickly using [`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) rather than the erroneous `strcpy()`. Either that or `malloc()` the proper space (string length +1), then use the `strcpy` as-is.

Comment: i did the strdup suggestion instead of strcpy and i still end up segmentaion faulting

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is probably more than malloc errors in your code. I have mentioned it in the comments.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct info {
    char* student;
    char* courseName;
    int grade;
};

int main()
{
    char buffer[100];
    struct info **strarray = NULL;  /*struct of Arrays*/
    char* token;
    char* studen = (char *) malloc(15);
    char* coursename = (char *) malloc(10);
    int grad, count = 0,index = 0;
    char* del = ",";
    FILE* fp = fopen("input-hw05a.csv", "r");

while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp) != NULL)
{
    token = strtok(buffer,del);
    studen = token;
    count = 0;    /* You missed it. Otherwise, count will never be 1 and 2 again when control enters the loop second time */
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        if(count == 1)
            coursename = token;
        if(count ==2)
        grad = atoi(token);

        token = strtok(NULL,del);
        count = count + 1;
    }
    /*add ONE element to the array*/
    strarray = (struct info **)realloc(strarray,(count + 1) * sizeof(struct info *));
    /*allocate memory for struct info*/
    strarray[index] = (struct info *)malloc(sizeof(struct info));
    /*copy data inso structure array*/
    strarray[index]->student = (char *)malloc(strlen(studen)*sizeof(char));  //you need to allocate memory for student, to do a string copy
    strcpy(strarray[index]->student,studen);
    strarray[index]->courseName = (char *)malloc(strlen(coursename)*sizeof(char)); // similarly, you need to allocate memory for coursename, to do a string copy
    strcpy(strarray[index]->courseName,coursename);
    strarray[index]->grade = grad;
    index = index + 1;
}
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < index; i++)
{
    printf("%s %s %d\n",strarray[i]->student,strarray[i]->courseName,strarray[i]->grade);  //In your code it was strarray[index]->courseName & strarray[index]->grade
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as written in the comments you have to malloc memory for student and courseName in the struct. I also removed the unnecassary mallocs

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct info {
char* student;
char* courseName;
int grade;
};



int main(void)
{
    char buffer[100];
    struct info **strarray = NULL;  /*struct of Arrays*/
    char* token;
    char* studen;
    char* coursename;
    int grad,count = 0,index = 0;
    char* del = ",";
    FILE* fp = fopen("input-hw05a.csv","r");

    while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp) != NULL)
    {
        token = strtok(buffer,del);
        studen = token;
        while(token != NULL)
        {
            if(count == 1)
                coursename = token;
            if(count ==2)
                grad = atoi(token);

            token = strtok(NULL,del);
            count++;
        }
        /*add ONE element to the array*/
        strarray = realloc(strarray,(index + 1) * sizeof(struct info *));

        /*allocate memory for struct info*/
        strarray[index] = malloc(sizeof(struct info));

        /*copy data inso structure array*/
        strarray[index]->student = malloc(strlen(studen)+1);
        strcpy(strarray[index]->student,studen);
        strarray[index]->courseName = malloc(strlen(coursename)+1);
        strcpy(strarray[index]->courseName,coursename);
        strarray[index]->grade = grad;
        index++;
    }
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %s %d\n",strarray[i]->student,strarray[index]->courseName,strarray[index]->grade);
    }
    //free all malloc memory
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above codes did not work for me.

Need to change below things:

1 . Add count=0 after the inner while loop, this is to reset the count so that it will read and store the data properly.
The way data was stored in your code is like:

Khai

IE 3301

69

Ashley

Alisaad

August

Ethan

As the count never comes back to 0, it does not change to 1 or 2 again.. so only the names are displayed.

2 . While displaying the data it uses strarray[index]->courseName,strarray[index]->grade. Since the Index is always incremented at the end. It will always point to something which will be allocated in next loop. Hence in last loop it points to memory which is not present and ending up in segmentation fault.

Comment: `If ptr is NULL, then the call is equivalent to malloc(size), for all values of size;` from the manual of `realloc`, so it has to work. It won't work with `calloc` since you will lose the last pointer.

Comment: One more issue with the code is that while displaying the data it uses strarray[index]->courseName,strarray[index]->grade. Since the Index is always incremented at the end. It will always point to something which will be allocated in next loop. Hence in last loop it points to memory which is not present and ending up in segmentation fault.